# When term is not selected, output specific text

Tags: views, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type, Article with a field 'Category' as term reference to 'category' taxonomy.

Category taxonomy has 2 terms, 'Live' and 'Outdoor'

Field's widget type is 'Check Boxes'.

- When Live is checked, it should say 'Program is Live'
- When Live is NOT checked, it should say 'Program is NOT Live'

[image]

- When Outdoor is checked, it should say 'Program is outdoor'
- When Outdoor is NOT checked, it should say 'Program is indoor'

[image]

Creating a terms view and using conditional field in view, I can check either value is empty or not, and can out put the desire result if there is only ONE term. But cant be done using multiple terms in the vocab.

When both are selected or not, every time both conditions are called for each term. And the output is true or false every time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use DDF module to implement this. 
Module url is https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is not about depending on the other field. Its about the output, depending on the selection of itself.

Comment: instead of using views conditional field, create views tpl and write conditions there.